# How can I get the Package version from a composer package

Tags: php, composer-php

I am currently dealing with something with the php composer theme. I have some github projects installed using composer and loaded with the autoload. Now I would like to find in my PHP code the current version number and packagename. How can I do that?

thanks

bjoern

Comment: what package name you want? You can check ``package.lock`` file in your root folder for the exact version installed on you system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing the dependencies, Composer writes the list of the exact versions it installed into a `composer.lock` file. You can parse `composer.lock` file to get version numbers and package names for all project's dependencies.